# How to use radio waves to calculate distance over short distances?

Tags: radio, distance

I read an article about a company that created the equivalent of a GPS location system for internal spaces where the satellite based GPS is blocked.  They made reference to the Fresnel number as to how it worked, but not much explanation beyond that.  So I have been looking at how this might be done and coming up blank.

Could you calculate distance using the Fresnel number?

Is the another method for distance calculation using radio waves for less than 50 meters?

Answer (score 1):

What you essential are describing is radar. The basic principle behind radar is you emit radiation in the direction of your target, and measure the time interval from emission to capture. You repeat this process and can measure an object's velocity and so on, however one of the fundamental problems with radar is the amount of noise that (inevitably) will be captured by the receiver.